# How to run "flash video" in full window?

Tags: browser, flash, video-streaming

for example on [www.pentaho.com](http://www.pentaho.com) there is a video, but I can't see anything. I would like to view it in full screen mode. Smart developers made that not an easy task. How to do it? Is there any plugin for it?

Comment: @techie007 good close, I hope you feel good being an a-hole. "generally relate to computer software" - sure.

Comment: @studiohack good close, I hope you feel good being an a-hole. "generally relate to computer software" - sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full screen is unavailable because of how the video was embedded. You can go for a pseudo fullscreen by manually zooming in on the video or using the Google Chrome browser tools extension.

Comment: thx, I will try that :)